# Maintaining DontDestroyOnLoad method after object becomes a child to another object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

in the game I am trying to make there is a level with moving platforms that make the player object a child for the duration of the collision.

```
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        collision.transform.SetParent(transform);
    }
 
    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        collision.transform.SetParent(null);
    }
```

Player does have a DontDestroyOnLoad method so he can move between the levels freely. However that method disappears whenever i come into contact with one of the moving platforms so the game crashes while going to the next level because the camera is using the player object to follow him and without player is missing a reference. I am pretty sure that the cause is that it becomes a child object of the platform and the platform itself does not use that method. Is there a way to keep the DontDestroyOnLoad method no matter the circumstances fn the player object?

Answer (score 0):

The scene cannot be loaded automatically. It is controlled by you, so you can unlink the player's parent before switching to the next scene.

```
player.transform.SetParent(null);
DontDestroyOnLoad(player.gameObject);
SceneManager.LoadScene("next scene");
```

Comment: I think it is not enough to unparent the object .. afaik you explicitly need to call `DontDestroyOnLoad` again in order to explicitly move it to the according scene again

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I will add this.

Comment: I just went ahead and reloaded player on each level since it does not really have any important stuff that i want to keep in between levels. I was just curious if there is a way to do this easily within the code. Thanks for help nonetheless.